# Data Access example using Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Does anyone know of or having any good examples of how to use Entity Framework version 2 in the Data Access layer and put an interface on it so the business layer uses the interface rather than knowing about EF? I have found some examples but they are all from 2009 and I'm not sure how they relate to Entity Framework version 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following link more helpful with separating the DAL and being able to apply TDD.

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/12/17/walkthrough-test-driven-development-with-the-entity-framework-4-0.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/walkthrough-test-driven-development-with-the-entity-framework-4-0)

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://aspalliance.com/1943_ASPNET_40_and_the_Entity_Framework_4__Part_4__A_3_Layered_Approach_to_the_Entity_Framework) specifically references Entity Framework 4, which is the *latest release* of EF.